# Can't use static const as param in function call within binding tags in Flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I'm having a problem in flex 3 where if a static const I have defined is used as the parameter to a function call within binding tags I get a "1120: Access of undefined property NodePropertyMatrix". _propMtx is a ArrayCollection.

```
<mx:HBox visible="{_propMtx.getItemAt(NodePropertyMatrix.srcParent)}">
```

Above code throws the error, but the following code does not

```
<mx:HBox visible="{NodePropertyMatrix.srcParent}">
```

NodePropertyMatrix is an AS class as follows:

```
package model.constants
{
import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

public class NodePropertyMatrix
{
    public static const srcParent:Number = 0;
}
}
```

Anyone know what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

In the mxml file where I was importing the NodePropertyMatrix is was doing this:

```
import Constants.*;
```

Instead of this:

```
import Constants.NodePropertyMatrix;
```

For some reason it doesn't work in this instance without explicity importing that class.  Wildcard didn't do the trick....not sure why, but ignorance is bliss.